# How to exclude the ending pattern in a search range?

Tags: search, range

I've the following content:

```
group1
  item1
  item2
  item3
group2
  item4
  item5
group3
  item6
```

where I'd like to select all items which belong to `group2` using a search range.

Here is my approach:

```
:/group2\n\zs/;,/^\ze\S/p
```

however it seems the `\ze` doesn't take any effect, because this is what is printed:

```
  item4
  item5
group3
```

I expect only `item4` and `item5` to be printed, without ending pattern (`group3`).

How do I exclude the ending pattern then?

Comment: That `,` is redundant btw. You could get the effect you want by changing `^` to `\n` in the second pattern, but you might be better off with offsets (e.g. `:/^group2/+;/^group/-p`) as noted in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think the atom `\ze` does take effect, it just doesn't prevent Vim to find a match on the `group3` line.
It's an empty match since you write `\ze` just after the anchor `^` which excludes everything afterwards. But even if it's empty, it's still something, the beginning of the line.

Maybe you could use an offset:

```
:/group2\n\zs/;,/^\ze\S/- p
                        ^
                        |___ minus sign, to decrease the line address by one
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach

```
:g/group2/+1,/group3/-1p
```